# \pscharpath within align environment

Tags: pstricks

Consider the following example:

```
% pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-text}

\newcommand*\R{\pscharpath[linewidth=0.25\pslinewidth,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]{R}}
\newcommand*\Gu{\pscharpath[linewidth=0.25\pslinewidth,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow]{Gu}}
\newcommand*\Gr{\pscharpath[linewidth=0.25\pslinewidth,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{Gr}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \Gr + \Gu + \R
\end{align*}
%\begin{equation*}
%  \Gr + \Gu + \R
%\end{equation*}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)
  \psline(0,0)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Question**

How do I use `\pscharpath` from the [`pst-text`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-text) package within an `align` environment correctly?

As you can see from the screenshot, I get a `\Gr` in the picture *after* the `align` environment instead of a `\psline`. If I use the `equation` environment instead of the `align` environment, everything is fine.

Comment: No problem with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`.

Comment: Then I get problems in my original document; I have to use `pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex`.

Comment: Because the auxiliary image file (`filename-pics.pdf`) contains 7 pages. In other words, `auto-pst-pdf` incorrectly uses the 4th page as the image for the figure environment.

Comment: Then why does it work if I use the `equation` environment?

Comment: It makes no sense to use the environment `align*` without columns. It is in this case the same as `\[ ... \]`

Comment: @Herbert I only used `align*` to get rid of the equation number in the example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ams` alignments are evaluated twice, you only want to add the hooks on the final run:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-text}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\R{\ifmeasuring@ R\else\pscharpath[linewidth=0.25\pslinewidth,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]{R}\fi}
\newcommand*\Gu{\ifmeasuring@ Gu\else\pscharpath[linewidth=0.25\pslinewidth,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow]{Gu}\fi}
\newcommand*\Gr{\ifmeasuring@ Gr\else\pscharpath[linewidth=0.25\pslinewidth,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{Gr}\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \Gr + \Gu + \R
\end{align*}
%\begin{equation*}
%  \Gr + \Gu + \R
%\end{equation*}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)
  \psline(0,0)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should it be regarded as a bug?

Comment: @mozartstraße It was a bug in the code in the question:-)

Comment: I meant the double evaluation in `align` sounds like a bug for me.

Comment: @mozartstraße No it's a documented feature (and why you can not hide `\begin{align}` in a macro or use verb etc the environment body is grabbed as a macro like tabularx or environ package. It _needs_ to measure all the cells to make the alignment.